# Añadir una fila a una jtable desde otro fame. La tabla no esta inicialmente vacía

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo un problema para añadir una nueva fila a la tabla y no sé que es lo que falla.
Tengo dos clases, una donde esta la tabla y la otra es donde estan distintos jtextFields. Pero cuando le doy a guardar no soy capaz de que se añada el contenido a la fila que se añade, se añade directamente la dila vacía.

Este es el botón de agregar que está en el jframe que contiene la tabla.

```
private class BtnAgregarActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            
            try {
                if(table.isShowing()) {
                    AgregarFila ap = new AgregarFila();
                    ap.setVisible(true);
                    Object[] row1= ap.getRow();
                    ap.pack();
                    ap.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    model.addRow(row1);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
```

Y este es el otro jframe con distintos JtextFields

```
private class BtnGuardarActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            row = new Object[] {
                    txtNombre.getText(),
                    
            };
            setRow(row);
            
        }
    }
```

```
private Object[] row;

    public Object[] getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(Object[] row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor si haces una instancia global para invocar ese otro JFrame y manipularlo desde el primer jframe. o sea usar el boton del segundo JFrame con el listener del primer jframe
te dejo un "ejemplo" debe tener errores de sintaxis porque no tengo java en esta PC y lo escribi en un bloc de notas.

/////primer jframe clase, donde esta la tabla

```
public class clase1 extends JFrame imlpements ActionListener {
  
  JTable table = new JTable
  DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
  JButton btnAbrirPantalla=new JButton("bt1");
  

//instancia
  AgregarFila ap = new AgregarFila();
  
 //contructor
 public  clase1(){  
 //...  
   btnAbrirPantalla.addActionListener(this);
 //ojo con este:
   ap.btnAgregaFila.addActionListener(this);        
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
 {
   if(btnAbrirPantalla==arg0.getSource())
   {
    ap.serVisible(true);
       //..y las propiedades que lleve este jframe 
   }
   if(ap.btnAgregaFila==arg0.getSource())
   {
     Object[] row = new Object[] {
        //ojo con este: ap.txtNombre
                    ap.txtNombre.getText(),      
            };

       model.addRow(row1);
       
       ap.setVisible(false);
   }

 }

  

}
/////el otro jframe, clase donde estan los textfield
public class AgregarFila extends JFrame{
  
  Jtextfield txtNombre=new JTextField();
  JButton btnAgregaFila=new JButton("bt2");
  //y todo lo demas que lleve este JFrame

}
```